# Unable to put equation number for a matrix written using figure command - IEEE Transaction

Tags: equations, numbering, matrices

I am using IEEE Transaction template which is in a double column format.

I have a large matrix which dows not fit in a single column. So, I used the figure option which spanned the matrix in both the columns.

However, I cannot put an Equation number. I need to refer this matrix in the text body. I have put the `\label` but in the text, there is no equation number.

If I don't explicitly put `\nonumber`, the latex throws compile error.

Is there a way so that the matrix gets assigned an equation number?  The following code display the matrix at the botto of the page. I want to display it where cited near the text in equation format, having an equation number.

```
The first sentence on the right column is not aligned with the first sentence in the left column. Also how to put a label to the equation so that I can refer it? What is the correct way acceptable in IEEE journal or in most journals for formatting these kind of matrices?
```

Comment: Aside: `\mathbf{\theta^* - \hat{\theta^*}}` cannot possibly work. I assume the following is roughly what you want: `\boldsymbol{\theta}^*-\hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}^*`

Answer (score 2):

First of all your example lacked a MWE. Second of all I invite you to read the `amsmath` documentation: those environment are really a blast.

You will see there that in `align*` the `*` has a different meaning, ie "non-numbered" environment, w.r.t `align`.

Here you don't need the `align` and can go with a simple equation. I also used the boldsymbol in the examples to render the bold `theta`, thaks to Mico

```
          \documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amsfonts,amssymb,bm}
    \begin{document}
     \begin{figure*}
\begin{equation}
A(\boldsymbol{\theta}^* - \hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}^*}) > \text{constant}
  \begin{psmallmatrix}
    {E[A]}^{-1} & 0 &0 & 0 & 0  \\[3ex]
    0 &   {E[B]}^{-1} &  0 & 0 & 0 \\[3ex]
  0  &   0 &  \bigl[E[{(\mathbf{h}^H\Re{\mathbf{s'}_n}){(\mathbf{h}^H\Re{\mathbf{s'}_n})^H}]\bigr]}^{-1} & 0 & 0\\[3ex]
  0 &  0 & 0  & 2\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}{E[{(\mathbf{h}^H\Im{\mathbf{s'}_n}){(\mathbf{h}^H\Im{\mathbf{s'}_n})}^H}]}^{-1} & 0 \\[3ex]
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & D
  \end{psmallmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{figure*}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Since your example occupies much of the page I would suggest to use placeholders for those big formulas and put them below:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amsfonts,amssymb,bm}
    \begin{document}
     \begin{figure*}
\begin{equation}
A(\boldsymbol{\theta}^* - \hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}^*}) > K
  \begin{pmatrix}
    E[A]^{-1} & 0 &0 & 0 & 0  \\
    0 &   E[B]^{-1} &  0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0  &   0 &  \alpha & 0 & 0\\
    0 &  0 & 0  &\beta  & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & D
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\begin{align*}
\text{where:}& \\
K&~\text{is a constant}\\
\alpha&=\bigl[E[{(\mathbf{h}^H\Re{\mathbf{s'}_n}){(\mathbf{h}^H\Re{\mathbf{s'}_n})}^H}]\bigr]^{-1}\\
\beta&=2\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}{E[{(\mathbf{h}^H\Im{\mathbf{s'}_n}){(\mathbf{h}^H\Im{\mathbf{s'}_n})}^H}]}^{-1}
\end{align*}
\end{figure*}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses a `pmatrix` environment along with the `bm` package. Note that I've replaced

```
A(\mathbf{\theta^* - \hat{\theta^*}})
```

(which, in any case, doesn't work) with

```
A(\bm{\theta}^* - \hat{\bm{\theta}}^*)
```

I've also gotten rid of lots of unneeded pairs of curly braces.

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,bm}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
\setlength\arraycolsep{4pt} % default: 5pt
\begin{equation}
A(\bm{\theta}^* - \hat{\bm{\theta}}^*) 
> \text{constant}
\begin{pmatrix}
E[A]^{-1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\[1.5ex]
0 & E[B]^{-1} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\[1.5ex]
0 & 0 &  
\Bigl[E\bigl[(\mathbf{h}^H\Re{\mathbf{s}'_n})
   (\mathbf{h}^H\Re{\mathbf{s}'_n})^H\bigr]
\Bigr]^{-1} 
& 0 & 0\\[1.5ex]
0 & 0 & 0 & 
2\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}E\bigl[(\mathbf{h}^H\Im{\mathbf{s}'_n})
(\mathbf{h}^H\Im{\mathbf{s}'_n})^H\,\bigr]^{-1} 
& 0 \\[1.5ex]
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & D
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}  
\end{figure*}    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

First I suggest you use the `strip` environment, from `cuted` (`sttools` bundle), so your equation won't float.

Second you don't need to use `psmallmatrix`, which makes its contents hard to read. Playing with `\arraycolsep`, you can use the normal`pmatrix`. Otherwise, one can use the `\medmath` command from `nccmath`, which types its contents in about 80 % of `\displaystyle`. Below is a demo of both.

Last, I removed a number of useless `{ }` pairs.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\RE}{Re}
\DeclareMathOperator{\IM}{Im}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{lipsum}

 \begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{strip}
\vspace*{-\stripsep}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
\setlength\arraycolsep{2pt}
A(\mathbf{\theta^* - \hat{\theta^*}}) > \text{constant}\cdot\!
 \begin{pmatrix}
 E[A]^{-1} & 0 &0 & 0 & 0 \\[1ex]
 0 &\! E[B]^{-1}\! & 0 & 0 & 0 \\[1ex]
 0 & 0 &\!\! \biggl[E\bigl[(\mathbf{h}^H\RE{\mathbf{s'}_n}){(\mathbf{h}^H\RE{\mathbf{s'}_n})}^H\bigr]\biggr]^{-1}\!\! & 0 & 0\\[1.5ex]
 0 & 0 & 0 & \!\!\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1}E\bigl[(\mathbf{h}^H\IM{\mathbf{s'}_n}){(\mathbf{h}^H\IM{\mathbf{s'}_n})}^H\bigr]^{-1} & 0 \\[1ex]
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & D
 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[4-5]
\begin{equation}\label{eq:2}
A(\mathbf{\theta^* - \hat{\theta^*}}) > \text{constant}\cdot\!
\medmath{\begin{pmatrix}
 E[A]^{-1} & 0 &0 & 0 & 0 \\[1ex]
 0 & E[B]^{-1} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\[1ex]
 0 & 0 &\biggl[E\bigl[(\mathbf{h}^H\RE{\mathbf{s'}_n}){(\mathbf{h}^H\RE{\mathbf{s'}_n})}^H\bigr]\biggr]^{-1} & 0 & 0\\[1.5ex]
 0 & 0 & 0 & \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1}E\bigl[(\mathbf{h}^H\IM{\mathbf{s'}_n}){(\mathbf{h}^H\IM{\mathbf{s'}_n})}^H\bigr]^{-1} & 0 \\[1ex]
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & D
 \end{pmatrix}}
\end{equation}
\vspace*{-\stripsep}
\end{strip}
\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The equation does not go at the bottom of the page, and  It looks neat and also saves a lot of space.  Thank you for this solution which I prefer over the others. However, I do find some problems which I have put in the updates part of the Question. Visually, on close inspection the colums are not coming aligned ? Also, waht is the utility of the command `\setlength\arraycolsep{2pt}` Please let me know how to rectify these.

Comment: The value of the horizontal distance between columns is decreased to 2pt (the default is 6pt, if I remember well). This doesn't make the matrix look too tight, because there are large entries which never are on the same row. For the labels, I've added a label to each of the equations in my code.  Last point: I have my columns bottom-aligned, but what you obtain might depend on the contents of the two columns above. Just in case, tryy the directive `\raggedbottom` in your preamble. Otherwise, could post a small code reproducing the problem?

Comment: I have included the code. I have several such large matrices in my article and for each I have used your approach. And the same problem of alignment of the column above the equation arises. Please see my updates. thank you

Comment: @SKM: There seems to be a problem with `IEEEtran.cls`: the same code, with `article.cls and `twocolumn` produces no misalignment. I'll try to understand why tomorrow, and if I can find a workaround.

Comment: Ok, thanks for looking at the problem. I will wait for your answer :)